# How do I set result of java.util.concurrent.Future?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

The Future interface doesn't provide a method for setting the result. In the docs, they say,

> A Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation. Methods
>   are provided to check if the computation is complete, to wait for its
>   completion, and **to retrieve the result of the computation**.

But I don't understand how do I set the result in the first place?

I was comparing `Future` to `DeferredResult` from Spring and they both *basically* represent the result of Async computation but `DeferredResult` has method for setting the result and `Future` doesn't?

Comment: Does not `FutureTask<V>` do what you need? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html "Since: 1.5"

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create your own class implementing `Future` and providing a setter (or extending [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and making the setter public), you can use the ready-made [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). It allows you to set the values, as well as a lot of other tricks that the `Future` interface doesn't show.

Comment: That's the problem, it was introduced in Java 8. I was looking for a Java 6/7 solution.

Comment: Then there is no "if you don't want to create your own class" option for you.